# Why can't I overload operator=?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, implicit-conversion, assignment-operator

I want to make following code work:

```
Mylist lst;
vector<int> v = lst;
```

So I see I need to convert my list into a vector.
I tried this code:

```
vector<int> operator=(vector<int> v, const List & l) {
    return v; // more profound stuff later :-)
}
```

(placed it outside the class). unfortunately Visual Studio throws me: "Error: 'operator=' must be a member function".
And I don't get it - what should I do? I can't place this function inside vector class...
Can you help me out with that?
Thanks!

Comment: Beyond the interesting case study of how to get this to work (which would be a cast operator) the bigger question is why you don't just say `vector<int> v = lst.getIntVector();`  When you get too clever with implicit behaviors you obscure costly operations, invite bugs, and make code harder to understand.  There should be a very measurable benefit to using such techniques.

Comment: To put my comment another way: do you *really* want `Mylist` to be usable and passed as a parameter anywhere one might use a vector of ints with no compiler warning--even though you know that it simply *isn't* a vector of ints...thus modifications of the implicitly produced vector will not be reflected back into the Mylist?  Wouldn't it be better to expose an iteration interface through `.begin()` and `.end()` so it could participate in generalized algorithms?  If you did that you wouldn't even have to supply an explicit extraction method like `getIntVector`...people could use `std::copy`...

Comment: [Why do some operators have to be members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938036/rationale-of-enforcing-some-operators-to-be-members)

Comment: What's wrong with `vector<int> v(lst.begin(), lst.end());`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can overload the cast of your type to any other type (see [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/) and other resources easily discoverable by Google). I think this is what you need here. Overloading the assignment operator is used for quite another thing in C++.

Comment: can you be more specific? what exactly should I do to make my code work?

Comment: @Tomy: see this SO discussion for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243962/c-operator-overloading-casting-from-class

Answer (score 3):

You can't overload operator for certain class outside this class. I gues vector is std::vector. What you could do is add to your "Mylist" class method toStdVector() const that would return std::vector.

For example:

```
class Mylist {
public:
  std::vector<int> toStdVector() const { ... }
};

Mylist list;
std::vector<int> v(list.toStdVector());
```

Comment: yeah, I know - but the question is, what should I do to make my code work?

Comment: Well just read my answer again and try to understand my sugestion

Answer (score 3):

```
Mylist lst;
vector<int> v = lst;
```

This doesn't call `operator=` to begin with. It attempt to call a constructor of vector which takes argument of type `Mylist`. Since no such constructor exists, it gives compilation error.

As for the question in the title, you can definitely overload `operator=`, but it cannot be a free-function. It has to be a member of a class.

Comment: The C++ states that “An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static member function” (§13.5.3/1), and GCC requires that as well.

Comment: @Philipp: Did I say anything else?

Comment: Basically this means you can't have an assignment operator where the left hand value is not your class.

Comment: @UncleBens: That is misleading. I can define my own class `A`. Now can I define `=` as free function such as `A a,b; a =b;`? Surely, the left hand side is my own defined class.

Answer (score 2):

To make
    MyList lst;
    std::vector v = lst;

To make the above work you'll need to overload `operator std::vector<int> ()` (or any other variable type that is compatible with `std::vector<int>`) in `MyList`, see the following example.

Another way of doing it is to provide a method that you explicitly call to return a `std::vector<int>` "*version*" of your object. `std::vector<int> v = obj.to_int_vector ()`, it's pretty much the same implementation as in the below example.

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct Obj {
  operator std::vector<int> () const {
    return std::vector<int> (data, data+3);
  }   

  int data[3];
};  

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   
  Obj o;

  o.data[0] = -1; 
  o.data[1] =  2;  
  o.data[2] = 99; 

  std::vector<int> v = o;

  std::copy (v.begin (), v.end (), std::ostream_iterator<int> (std::cout, " "));
}
```

output:

```
-1 2 99
```

Answer (score 1):

You may provide `operator vector<int>` So if you put `vector<int> v = lst;`, the operator vector` would be called and operator= for vector will be allowed.

```
class MyList {
public:

operator vector<int> () const
{
    return some_valid_vector;
}
};
```